# Rewrite not working with dynamic URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a site built with a MVC platform that arranges codes like domainname.com/login/ where login is not a folder, it is an action (URL rewrite method).

mysite.com/ is pointing correctly to the home folder index file, but when i try to access mysite.com/login/ I can't (it says: The requested URL /login/ was not found on this server). BTW I can access http://"siteip"/mysite/login/ with no problem.

I've set my .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?request=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `http://"siteip"/mysite/login/` URL? Do you mean using IP you can access this page?

Comment: Yes @anubhava, using IP i can access.

Comment: ok then check Apache config. With domain it might be going to different `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: My homepage works good, the www.mysite.com/ opens correctly. But all other pages (dinamic url) only open using IP. Mod_rewrite is enabled in Apache.